# Syndrome Computation Patterson's Algorithm

Tags: decryption, mceliece, code-based-cryptography

Suppose in Patterson's algorithm for the correction of binary Goppa codes, we wish to compute the syndrome polynomial when the defining polynomial is $g(x) = x^{4} + x + 1$, and the error polynomial is  $e(x) = x^{3} + x^{14} + x^{7}$ where these are polynomials over $\mathbb F_{16}$ where we write $F_{16} := F_{2}[\gamma]/\langle \gamma^4+\gamma+1\rangle$.

The syndrome would be $S(x) := \dfrac{1}{x+\gamma^{3}} + \dfrac{1}{x+\gamma^{7}} + \dfrac{1}{x+\gamma^{14}}\mod{g(x)}$.

What method can be used to calculate $\dfrac{1}{x+\gamma^{3}}$ = $\gamma^{10}x^{3} + \gamma^{13}x^{2} + \gamma^{1}x + \gamma^{2}\mod{g(x)}$? I want to figure out the other two fractions and eventually write this as a $S(x) = \gamma^5x^3 + \gamma^3x^2+\gamma^2x + 0$ , but getting stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ext-GCD to find the inverse...

Comment: I've been trying that .. can't seem to figure out where the coefficients γ5, γ3, γ2, etc come from.

Comment: Your question actually is not clear. In $F_{16} := F_{2}[\gamma]/\langle \gamma^4+\gamma+1\rangle$, we use $\gamma^4 = \gamma+1$ for the reduction.

Answer (score 2):

We treat $g(x)$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb F_{16}[x]$ and compute
$\frac1{x+\gamma^3}\pmod{g(x)}$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm to find $u(x)$ such that $u(x)(x+\gamma^3)+v(x)g(x)=1$. The polynomial $u(x)$ can then used as $\frac1{x+\gamma^3}$ in Patterson's algorithm. For the purposes of the calculation, it is useful to write elements of $\mathbb F_{16}$ as powers of $\gamma$ thus:

| $n$ | $\gamma^n$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | $\gamma$ |
| 2 | $\gamma^2$ |
| 3 | $\gamma^3$ |
| 4 | $\gamma+1$ |
| 5 | $\gamma^2+\gamma$ |
| 6 | $\gamma^3+\gamma^2$ |
| 7 | $\gamma^3+\gamma+1$ |
| 8 | $\gamma^2+1$ |
| 9 | $\gamma^3+\gamma$ |
| 10 | $\gamma^2+\gamma+1$ |
| 11 | $\gamma^3+\gamma^2+\gamma$ |
| 12 | $\gamma^3+\gamma^2+\gamma+1$ |
| 13 | $\gamma^3+\gamma^2+1$ |
| 14 | $\gamma^3+1$ |
| 15 | 1 |
| $15a+b$ | $\gamma^b$ |

To walk through the steps, we have
$$(x^4+x+1)+(x^3+\gamma^3x^2+\gamma^6x+\gamma^7)(x+\gamma^3)=\gamma^5,$$
so that we may take $u(x)=\gamma^{10}(x^3+\gamma^3x^2+\gamma^6x+\gamma^7)$ and $v(x)=\gamma^{10}$. Thus $u(x)=\gamma^{10}x^3+\gamma^{13}x^2+\gamma x+\gamma^2$. You should be able to duplicate this process to find expressions for $\frac1{x+\gamma^7}$ and $\frac1{x+\gamma^{14}}$. Adding the three expressions together will then give $S(X)$.